# How can I make this toggle switch responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make (using `React`) a toggle switch I found responsive so that I can put it in my app but I'm having trouble refactoring it to resize based on content inside and device width/height.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

import styles from "./ToggleSwitch.module.css";

export default function ToggleSwitch({ choice1, choice2 }) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(choice2);

    function handleClick() {
        setValue(value => (value === choice1 ? choice2 : choice1));
    }

    function styleToggleSwitch(value) {
        if (value === choice1) {
            return { clipPath: "inset(0 0 0 50%)", backgroundColor: "#eb9b30" };
        } else {
            return { clipPath: "inset(0 50% 0 0)", backgroundColor: "#1464cf" };
        }
    }

    return (
        <div id={styles["container"]} onClick={handleClick}>
            <div className={styles["inner-container"]}>
                <div className={styles["toggle"]}>
                    <p>{choice2}</p>
                </div>
                <div className={styles["toggle"]}>
                    <p>{choice1}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div
                className={styles["inner-container"]}
                style={
                    value === choice1
                        ? styleToggleSwitch(choice1)
                        : styleToggleSwitch(choice2)
                }
            >
                <div className={styles["toggle"]}>
                    <p>{choice2}</p>
                </div>
                <div className={styles["toggle"]}>
                    <p>{choice1}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap:400,500,700");

#container {
    width: 160px;
    height: 36px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: "Asap", sans-serif;
}

.inner-container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
}

.inner-container:first-child {
    background: #e9e9e9;
    color: #a9a9a9;
}

.inner-container:nth-child(2) {
    background: dodgerblue;
    color: white;
    clip-path: inset(0 50% 0 0);
    transition: 0.3s cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

.toggle {
    width: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    height: inherit;
    display: flex;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.toggle p {
    margin: auto;
}

.toggle:nth-child(1) {
    right: 0;
}
```

When I select the toggle switch buttons they get either the `.first` or `.second` class to change their styles. Sorry for using pastebin but Stack Overflow wouldn't allow me to post this much code. Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: You can set `width: 100%;` for `#container`. Is this the desired result?

Comment: @user4980215 No because when I change between the 2 values I render different components with different widths so if I have 100% the widths with shift.